# Каждому элементу столбца матрицы добавить соответствующий элемент побочной диагонали

Tags: c++, матрицы

В матрице n*n элементов нужно каждому элементу столбца добавить соответствующий элемент побочной
диагонали.
Алгоритм составления матрицы представлен ниже:

```
 X=new int*[n];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
            X[i] = new int[n];
        }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            X[i][j]= i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы два раза матрицу заполняете?  Приведите пример `каждому элементу столбца добавить соответствующий элемент побочной диагонали.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Нужно будет поменять порядок итераций по сравнению с кодом заполнения, чтобы во внешнем цикле обрабатывать *столбцы*.
- Для каждого столбца запомнить соответствующий элемент на побочной диагонали: для `i`-го столбца это будет элемент в строке с индексом `n - 1 - i`
- Проходя во вложенном цикле *по строкам*, прибавить соответствующее значение.

Код не приводится, так как задание учебное, и он сам по себе тривиален.